# How to Refresh Page from C# from Function in a Class

Tags: c#

I have MainView in RequestController which handle request and open an App from Mobile Phone after the request is sent.

When user closed the App from the Mobile Phone, it will trigger my api in ApiController which then will call Refresh function from a class code.

At this point, I want to refresh MainView, the page where user left before, after the App is opened on Mobile Phone. I cannot hardcode it to refresh MainView, since it may come from other page later like SubView or something else. It should be redirected to the last view, right before the request is sent.

I tried to use Server.Transfer but it failed.
I tried to use Redirect and Response.Redirect but nothing happened.

I want to try calling javascript, but the Page is null.

Is there any idea for this kind of scenario?

More Info:

Using NET Framework 4.0

Mobile App is from another 3rd party company, the request from my controller call the js file, which invoke the app to be opened from Android or iOS. When the app closed, it will call the registered log url.
In this case, it is on my ApiController.

Comment: could you please add details, like which framework you are using for Mobile client, server etc.?

Comment: Hi, I added some more info above

Comment: how do you link mobile app user (which calls API controller) and website user which browses the site?

Comment: Behind the scenes, in some website pages. There is button which will call the 3rd party mobile app js library function and automatically open an App.  At first, when we call the js library function, we have to put parameter of event Url which it will call when the mobile app is closed.

In my case, the website and the callback event url for mobile app, is in one server. So, I think it is possible to refresh the website which the user has left when the Mobile App is automatically opened before. Just don't know how for now.

Comment: can you send a parameter to the mobile app (page from where user left) and then get it back when the app is closed?

Comment: Unfortunately, no